# почему у меня при навидениие курсором на кнопу в месте с изменением её размера меняется и положение бэкраунда

Tags: css

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(122deg, #404040, #141414);
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  width: auto;
  padding: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 30px;
  border: solid 2px #0068a0;
  color: #000000;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 5px #000000;
  background-color: #004cbe;
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 0px #015264;
}

.btn:hover {
  width: auto;
  padding: 48px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
}

.btn:focus {
  background-color: #003481;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="btn_background">
    <button class="btn">Click</button>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Для начала объясните зачем вам в коде эти свойства: `align-items`, `margin-left`, `margin-right`, `width`? Если вы сами не понимаете назначения свойств, то лучше сначала прочитать про них и про то, где они используются.

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется проблема в размере кнопки **btn:hover** , наводишь на кнопку меняется размер и соответственно и положение и фоновый градиэнт.
Добавь   **transform: scale(0.96);**